# Creating ArrayList by calling method that returns ArrayList while looping through map

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, graph

```
//add the edges for each vertex
    for(Map.Entry<Vertex,ArrayList<Vertex>> entry : mGraph.entrySet()) {
        Vertex key = entry.getKey();
        //System.out.println(key);
        ArrayList<Vertex> temp2  = createAdj(key);

        System.out.println(temp2);
}

//method that returns list of adjcencies for nodes
public ArrayList<Vertex> createAdj(Vertex v){

    temp = new ArrayList<Vertex>();
    char oppositeColor = flipColor(v.color);

    //Nodes that point south
    if(v.direction == "S"){
        if(v.row != 7){

            for(Vertex i: storage){

                if(i.col == v.col && i.row > v.row && i.color == oppositeColor){

                    temp.add(i);

                }

            }
        }
    }


    //node that point North
    if(v.direction == "N"){
        if(v.row != 1){

            for(Vertex i: storage){

                if(i.col == v.col && i.row < v.row && i.color == oppositeColor){

                    temp.add(i);

                }

            }
        }
    }


    //node that point West
    if(v.direction == "W"){
        if(v.col != 1){

            for(Vertex i: storage){

                if(i.row == v.row && i.col < v.col && i.color == oppositeColor){

                    temp.add(i);

                }

            }
        }
    }


    //node that point East
    if(v.direction == "E"){
        if(v.col != 7){

            for(Vertex i: storage){

                if(i.row == v.row && i.col > v.col && i.color == oppositeColor){

                    temp.add(i);

                }

            }
        }
    }

    //node that points southeast
    if(v.direction == "SE"){

        if(v.row != 7 ||v.col != 7){

            int tempRow = v.row;
            int tempColumn = v.col;

            while(tempRow < 7 && tempColumn < 7){

                tempRow++;
                tempColumn++;

                for(Vertex i: storage){

                    if(i.row == tempRow && i.col == tempColumn && i.color == oppositeColor)
                        temp.add(i);

                }
            }

        }

    }


    //node that points northeast
    if(v.direction == "NE"){

        if(v.row != 1 ||v.col != 7){

            int tempRow = v.row;
            int tempColumn = v.col;

            while(tempRow != 1 && tempColumn != 7){

                tempRow--;
                tempColumn++;

                for(Vertex i: storage){

                    if(i.row == tempRow && i.col == tempColumn && i.color == oppositeColor)
                        temp.add(i);

                }
            }

        }

    }


    //node that points southwest
    if(v.direction == "SW"){

        if(v.row != 7 ||v.col != 1){

            int tempRow = v.row;
            int tempColumn = v.col;

            while(tempRow != 7 && tempColumn != 1){

                tempRow++;
                tempColumn--;

                for(Vertex i: storage){

                    if(i.row == tempRow && i.col == tempColumn && i.color == oppositeColor)
                        temp.add(i);

                }
            }

        }

    }


    //node that points northwest
    if(v.direction == "NW"){

        if(v.row != 1 ||v.col != 1){

            int tempRow = v.row;
            int tempColumn = v.col;

            while(tempRow > 1 && tempColumn > 1){

                tempRow--;
                tempColumn--;

                for(Vertex i: storage){

                    if(i.row == tempRow && i.col == tempColumn && i.color == oppositeColor)
                        temp.add(i);

                }
            }

        }

    }

    return temp;
}


public class Vertex  {

    //name of vertex and a pointer to the first node in its adj linked list

    public int row;
    public int col;
    public char color;
    public String direction;
    public String isCircle;


    public Vertex(int row, int col, char color, String isCircle, String direction) {
        super();
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
        this.color = color;
        this.isCircle = isCircle;
        this.direction = direction;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vertex [row=" + row + ", col=" + col + ", color=" + color
                + ", direction=" + direction + ", isCircle=" + isCircle + "]";
    }
}
```

I am in the process of creating a directed graph using adjacency lists. The loop in the first box is scanning through the keys in a map I had created earlier, which are the nodes that need their corresponding adjacencies. However, when I try doing a system out on the adjacencies being created not all of them are being created. The createAdj() method is mostly a lot of code redundancy, but I have done numerous tests on the method, and I am sure that it returns the correct list everytime I put a Vertex object into it. Yet it does not work in the for loop above. Also, I am sure that the for loop is looping through the keys in the map correctly. The output of the code above is, without the extra spaces:

```
[]
[]
[]
[Vertex [row=1, col=4, color=R, direction=NW, isCircle=N], Vertex [row=1, col=5, color=R, direction=S, isCircle=N]]
[]
[Vertex [row=5, col=7, color=R, direction=NE, isCircle=N]]
```

Not sure why some lists get created and others dont.

Comment: If you're creating a plane map, why use a Map of lists? Why not a Map of Maps denoting the board `Map<Row, Map<Column, Vertex>>()` or better yet just a multidimensional array `Vertex[][]`? It seems strange to tell a vertex where it is internally rather than tell your plot/map/board where it is. The math gets a lot easier if you do it that way, as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the lists are being created, that's why they print out as `[]` instead of being `null`. They just have no adjacent vertices being added to the lists. I do notice that you are not, however, setting the generated list back to the value in your graph.

```
entry.setValue(temp2);
```

If you're using Java8, you can generate values in your map using `computeIfAbsent`:

```
Map<Vertex, List<Vertex>> mGraph = new ConcurrentHashMap<Vertex,List<Vertex>>();

for (Vertex vertex : mGraph.keySet()){
    List<Vertex> adjacentVertices = mGraph.computeIfAbsent(vertex, this::createAdj);
    //adjacentVertices now contains my initialized list, so do something
}
```

One other cardinal sin: You are using `==` to do string comparison. You should not. Instead of:

```
someString == "This"
```

you should do

```
"This".equals(someString);
"This".equalsIgnoreCase(someString);
```

So instead of `if(v.direction == "S"){` it should be `if("S".equals(v.direction))`. Using `==` is not guaranteed to work correctly. The `==` operator tests for reference equality (whether two things are literally the same object in memory, which they WILL NOT be when one of them's a literal), while `.equals()` tests for VALUE equality. And call `.equals()` on your literal as a matter of preference, since you know your literal will never be null and therefore can't throw a `NullPointerException`. `"S".equals(someString)` is false when `someString` is `null`, but `someString.equals("S")` throws a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that it is a 7x7 board. The rule for the graph is that ALL adjacencies can only be created with nodes that are opposite color and are within the direction of the parent node's cardinal direction. So adjacencies are not created just by the nodes that are adjacent to the parent node. They can be created with nodes at the other end of the board, depending on the nodes cardinal direction

Comment: So your rule for "adjacent" is just "has direction equal to my direction and has color opposite to my color and has coordinates greater than mine in my direction"?

Comment: Yes. I am just using my map called mGraph: <Vertex, ArrayList<Vertex>> as my adjacency list to represent the graph. So each node has its own [adjacency list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list)

Comment: So basically it's a Queen Move formula in chess... your 'adjacency list' is "Which opposite colored spaces will my Queen move through if I move her as far as I can in direction X" Your math seems very complicated for that.

Comment: Ya I kind of brute forced that method, but I am sure it works. The problem is to model a maze as a directed graph. Then run an algorithm to solve it. I cant for the life of me find a picture of the maze on the internet. But I have been testing the creataAdj() method on almost all of my nodes outside of that, and it works perfectly.

Comment: The algorithm to solve a maze is easy; just turn left at every possible opportunity. Come to a dead end, turn left, and try to move again. Still at a dead end? Turn left and try to move again (you're now facing the direction you came from). Come to an intersection, turn left. Eventually you'll trace every possible route until you find the one that leads to the exit of the maze. It's the brute force method, but it's by far the simplest algorithm. As for modeling it, I don't know what your initial specs are, but your model seems a bit complicated.

Comment: Im not concerned about not solving it. Once I model the graph correctly, I can just use a BFS algorithm to do all the work. The trick is modeling the graph correctly first. By the way, thanks for helping so far. I am just wondering if I am creating the ArrayList the right way. Its the only main reason I can think of thats causing the problem.

Comment: I would suggest changing all of your variables and types defined as `<ArrayList>` to `<List>` since you may not get an `ArrayList` back from certain operations. Plus, the type of your `temp` variable in the `createAdj()` method isn't defined in the method. Is that intentional?

Comment: My answer's changed radically.

Comment: I figured it out. I should not be comparing strings with ==. It should be v.direction != null && v.direction.equals("X"). Where X is the direction

Comment: I do believe I said that in my answer, but better. :-)